# 'image-rendering: pixelated;' like on ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

With CSS you can add style to img tag with 'image-rendering: pixelated;'.

Is there a way to do it in Android with similar effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it (turning anti-aliasing off) by setting **`setFilterBitmap(false)`** to `Drawable` object (or `Paint` object when using `Canvas`).

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);
drawable.setFilterBitmap(false);

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```